# RSpec RoutingError for nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing a nested controller and get the following error:

```
  1) Checklists::ItemsController index action should render index template
     Failure/Error: get :index, :checklist_id => checklist.id
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:checklist_id=>1, :controller=>"checklists/items"}
```

In the browser loading /checklists/1/items loads fine.

Am I missing something in the spec?

The routes:

```
  resources :checklists do
    resources :items, :controller => "Checklists::Items"
  end
```

The controller located in namespaced folder (**/app/controllers/checklists/items_controller.rb**):

```
class Checklists::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @checklist_items = @checklist.items
    respond_with @checklist_items
  end
end
```

The spec (**/spec/controllers/checklists/items_controller_spec.rb**):

```
describe Checklists::ItemsController do
  let(:user) { Factory :user, :role => 'admin' }
  let(:checklist) { Factory(:checklist) }
  let(:checklist_item) { Factory(:checklist_item) }

  before(:each) do
    sign_in_to(controller, user)
    Checklist.stub(:find => checklist)
  end

  it "index action should render index template" do
    get :index, :checklist_id => checklist.id
    response.should render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

Update: Routes for checklist items

```
checklist_items GET    /checklists/:checklist_id/items(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"Checklists::Items"}
                POST   /checklists/:checklist_id/items(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"Checklists::Items"}
new_checklist_item GET    /checklists/:checklist_id/items/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"Checklists::Items"}
edit_checklist_item GET    /checklists/:checklist_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"Checklists::Items"}
 checklist_item GET    /checklists/:checklist_id/items/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"Checklists::Items"}
                PUT    /checklists/:checklist_id/items/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"Checklists::Items"}
                DELETE /checklists/:checklist_id/items/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"Checklists::Items"}
```

Comment: What's the output of rake routes?

Comment: Updated the post to include the routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the solution to the problem was in the routes:

I changed

```
resources :items, :controller => "Checklists::Items"
```

to

```
resources :items, :controller => "checklists/items"
```

and it works now